# double if then in sas

Tags: if-statement, sas

I want to write a code like this:

```
 DATA TEST;
        SET original;
        IF hour = 30 AND minutes = . or 0 THEN new_minutes = 30;
        ELSE if hour = 60 AND minutes = . or 0 then new_minutes = 60;

RUN;
```

If I used
         IF hour = 30 and minutes = . OR minutes = 0 THEN new_minutes = 30; THEN even if the new value should be 60 it changes to 30. I there a way to get around this besides changing all 0 to . (or all . to 0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need ( ).

```
IF hour = 30 AND (minutes = . or minutes = 0) THEN new_minutes = 30;
```

Or you could use the `in` statement

```
IF hour = 30 AND minutes in ( . , 0) THEN new_minutes = 30;
```

Comment: That's exactly what I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `coalesce` for this; that returns the first nonmissing result.

```
if hour = 30 and coalesce(minutes,0) = 0 then minutes=30;
```

I would also suggest that you could write it this way to simplify the code:

```
if hour in (30,60) and coalesce(minutes,0) = 0 then minutes=hour;
```

And you could even generalize that first part potentially, depending on what are otherwise legal value for hour.  If hour can't be over 24 then

```
if hour > 24 and coalesce(minutes,0) = 0 then minutes=hour;
```

Would be one possibility, as well as checking to see if hour is divisible by 15 or 10 or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

You could even write it without any `if` statements, providing you can accept `new_minutes` being zero if the criteria are not satisfied :

```
data want ;
  set have ;
  new_minutes = (hour in(30,60) and minutes in(.,0)) * hour ;
run ;
```